# Unable to install Rasa and use it on PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation, rasa

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-addons<0.9,>=0.8 (from rasa) (from versions: )`
`No matching distribution found for tensorflow-addons<0.9,>=0.8 (from rasa)`

I keep on getting this error while performing
`pip3 install rasa`
I've tried it with Python 3.8,3.7 and 3.6.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect all your Pythons are 32-bit. TensorFlow and addons require 64-bit Python.

Check bitness of your Pythons:

```
python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
```

If they're really 32-bit uninstall them all and install 64-bit Python.