# how to install "pip install rasa", I am getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am getting the below error while i am trying for "pip install rasa". My Python Version is 3.7.8.

Error message :

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<2.9,>=2.8 in c:\users\loginname\desktop\2020\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages (from rasa) (2.8.1)
Collecting colorhash<1.1.0,>=1.0.2
  Using cached colorhash-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.0 kB)
Collecting ujson<3.0,>=1.35
  Using cached ujson-2.0.3.tar.gz (7.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\loginname\desktop\2020\chatbot\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\loginname\desktop\2020\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\loginname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nir8n2vw\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (42 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\loginname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "C:\Users\loginname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "c:\users\loginname\desktop\2020\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
      sys.exit(_main())
    File "c:\users\loginname\desktop\2020\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
      command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
    File "c:\users\loginname\desktop\2020\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
      module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
    File "C:\Users\loginname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

Comment: try pip3 install rasa.

Comment: I am receiving the same error

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade the pip first and fetch the rasa after. It seem like you already have the cached version of rasa in your site packages though.

Comment: my pip version  right now is (20.2.1) "Requirement already up-to-date: pip"

Comment: Is that all of the errors? I think there are more relevant/useful error messages at the end, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60686573/2745495).

Comment: yes, the error seems more than 5000 characters, i do not know how to post the whole error message

Comment: I can't because I don't know what error you have. You don't need to post the *entire* log and traceback, just those parts that show "ERROR" (it is usually towards the end of the log). On my machine and with Python3.7, the error is this: "*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-addons<0.8.0,>=0.7.1 (from rasa) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow-addons<0.8.0,>=0.7.1 (from rasa)"*

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip
$ python3 -m venv ./venv
$ source ./venv/bin/activate
$ pip install -U pip
$ pip install rasa
```

https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/installation/